# Problem adding PDF Form upload to Magento 2.1

Tags: magento-2.1

I am trying to create a PDF upload attached to product in Magento 2.1 I am able to get the form to display but it is not generating a field "name" which I believe is required for the form upload.

From what I understand the form field name should be "pdf" but this is not displaying when viewing the source code

```
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">


<fieldset name="pdf_upload">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Product PDF Upload</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">999999</item>
            <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="opened" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
        </item>
    </argument>

    <field name="pdf">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">product</item>

            <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Select A File</item>
            <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
            <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">40</item>
            <item name="notice" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Only PDFs are allowed</item>
            <item name="maxFileSize" xsi:type="number">209715200</item>
            <item name="allowedExtensions" xsi:type="string">pdf</item>

            <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="productinformation/product_pdf/upload"/>
            </item>

        </argument>

    </field>

</fieldset>
```